# Hosting webapp made with nodejs view engine

Tags: node.js, ejs, netlify, netlify-function

I have created a webapp which is rendering its page using view engine. All the .ejs files containing html codes are lying inside the views folder. And all the functionalities used to render/redirect/database connection are lies inside a folder called "functionalities".

Now I want to host the website on netlify. But the folder structure is different than mine. How can I host the webapp whithout restructuring the folder structure.

I have searched on the youtube and google. But not enough resource is on this topic.